# Makefile: copy perl/python files from source directory into build directory

Tags: c++, build, makefile

I have the following source directory structure

```
src:
    dir1: c++ files, Makefile
    dir2: perl/python scripts, Makefile


build:
    bin: 
        binary-executables
        bin-subdir: I want my perl/python files to be copied during the build process.
```

Also, When I do a `make install`, will the `bin-subdir` be copied into `install/bin` by default or I have to specify that as well?

Comment: That depends on what is in your makefiles, especially under the `install` target and any of its prerequisites or sub-targets.

Comment: You are right. I got used to CMake and expected some things to happen by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you run `make X`, you are telling Make to find target `X` in your Makefile. So if you have no `install:` target, nothing will happen. All of this really depends what is in your Makefiles. If you want to copy your perl/python files into the build directory, one way to do so is to write a Makefile target that runs a *sh command like `mv dir2/*.pyc build; mv dir2/*.pl build`, and require that target somewhere else in your Makefile. If you need a good Makefile tutorial, [here's one that I started with.](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)